# issue with calling a javascript function twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

I am trying to write a fairly simple Javascript function, and experiencing behavior I don't understand when I iterate the function.

I have distilled the problem down to the following situation. I want to write a function that will take as input an array consisting of arrays of arrays, e.g. `A = [[[1]]]`. I don't know the standard terminology for this, so I am going to refer to the main array as "level 0", which has elements that are arrays of "level 1". I'll say the level 1 arrays consist of arrays of "level 2". The level 2 arrays consist of integers.

The function does the following, on input `A` (a level 0 array):

1. create an empty array `L`;
2. for each level 1 array `M` in `A`

   - add one to each integer entry in each level 2 array in `M`;
   - add two copies of `M` to `L`
3. return `L`.

Here is my code:

```
function myFunc(A){
  var L = [];
  for(var a=0; a<A.length; a++){
    var M = A[a].slice(0);
    for(var i=0; i<M.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<M[i].length; j++){
        M[i][j]++;
      }
    }
    for(var s=0; s<2; s++){
      var N = M.slice(0);
      L.push(N);
    }
  }
  return(L);
}
```

Now I test it out:

```
var A = [[[1]]];

A = myFunc(A)
```

After this, I get `A = [[[2]],[[2]]]`, which is what I expect. However, suppose I iterate it:

```
var A = [[[1]]];

A = myFunc(A);

A = myFunc(A);
```

Then I expect to obtain `A = [[[3]],[[3]],[[3]],[[3]]]`, but instead I have `A = [[[4]],[[4]],[[4]],[[4]]]`.

On the other hand if I run `myFunc([[[2]],[[2]]])`, I do get the expected `[[[3]],[[3]],[[3]],[[3]]]`.

I don't understand where this discrepancy is coming from.

Comment: That's not the issue. The function when called twice does not have the same results, read his question again. I'm investigating and I got a lead I think

Comment: Its probably a referenced value vs a copied one. Try A = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A)) between your A = myFunct(A) calls. I cannot test I am on my iPhone

Comment: @FlavienVolken yes that does solve it but I do not understand why it's failing here. :o

Comment: Still digging, weird behavior found, do `x = [[[1]]]` and then call `myFunc(x)` multiple times.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with var M = A[a].slice(0). Since it's a multidimensional array, it gets a reference to the original A array. Then when you increment M[i][j]++ it's altering A. Same as what @TristanFoureur   found in his answer :)

Comment: @concrete_d You're right. Just added a quote and a link to mozilla's doc which states clearly

Comment: FYI: `return` is not a function, so the parentheses around the return value aren't necessary.

Comment: Just added why `myFunc([[[2]],[[2]]])` yields a different result as `var A = [[[1]]];

A = myFunc(A);

A = myFunc(A);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
M[i][j]++;
```

Node keeps this as a reference to your A's slice, and you see it clearly when you do this :

```
x = [[[1]]];
myFunc(x);
myFunc(x);
console.log(x); // ---> [[[3]]]
```

For a shallow copy you'd have to use the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` trick, and proof that M is the problem; adding this line just after `M = A[a].slice(0);` solves the issue.

```
M = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(M))
```

Mozilla's documentation about `Array.prototype.slice()` :

> For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object
>   references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer
>   to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are
>   visible to both the new and original arrays.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

That is why, because when you do `M[i][j]`, the array a level deeper is still referenced outside.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Tristan Foureur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594695/2041954) has already pointed out what caused the discrepancy, I just wanted to add in why

```
var A = [[[1]]];

A = myFunc(A);
A = myFunc(A);
```

gives a different result versus

```
myFunc([[[2]],[[2]]])
```

---

When doing `myFunc([[[2]],[[2]]])`, what you are basically doing is `myFunc(new Array(new Array(new Array(2))),(new Array(new Array(2)))))`.

So when the V8 engine elevates this line

```
var M = A[a].slice(0);
```

it would interpret `A[a].slice(0)` as

```
new Array(new Array(new Array(2))),(new Array(new Array(2))))[a].slice(0)
```

and hence you get 2 (from the new Array) every time it is called.

This can be seen if you examine the function with logs:

```
function myFunc(A){
  var L = [];
  console.log("A is"+ JSON.stringify(A));
  for(var a=0; a<A.length; a++){
    var M = A[a].slice(0);
    console.log("M is"+ JSON.stringify(M) + " while A is" +JSON.stringify(A),a); 
    for(var i=0; i<M.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<M[i].length; j++){
        M[i][j]++;
      }
    }
    for(var s=0; s<2; s++){
      var N = M.slice(0);
      L.push(N);
      console.log("L.push:"+ JSON.stringify(N));
    }
  }
  console.log("the end" + JSON.stringify(L), JSON.stringify(A));
  return(L);
}

var A = [[[1]]];
A = myFunc(A);
A = myFunc(A);
var t = myFunc([[[2]],[[2]]]);
```

If you replace `var M = A[a].slice(0);` with

```
var M = new Array(new Array(new Array(2))),(new Array(new Array(2))))[a].slice(0)
```

and run through the function without A, you would see `[[[3]],[[3]],[[3]],[[3]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned the issue is that the `M.slice` call only did a shallow copy. They have also given good solutions for how to do a deepcopy. I'd propose that you really don't need to do the copy at all though:

```
var L = [];
for (var iLevel1 = 0; iLevel1 < A.length; iLevel1++)
{
    for (var iLevel2 = 0; iLevel2 < A[iLevel1].length; iLevel2++)
    {
        for (var iLevel3 = 0; iLevel3 < a[iLevel1][iLevel2].length; iLevel3++)
           L.push(a[iLevel1][iLevel2][iLevel3] + 1); 
    }
}

return L.concat(L);
```